# Ajax script not function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a request with ajax that still loads the `php` script instead of performing its function without refreshing. Am guessing there is an issue with my `ajax` Below is anything wrong with the ajax script

**HTML**

```
<form action='connect_exec.php' method='post' id='connect_form' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input type='text' name='conn_id' id='conn_id' value='$ad_id'>
    <input type='submit' name='connect' class='conn_text' id='connect' value='connect +'>
</form>
```

**Ajax request**

```
$('#connect_form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var ad_id = $('#conn_id').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "connect_exec.php",
        data: ad_id
    }).done(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }).fail(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

**PHP SCRIPT**

```
require_once("db.php");
$db = new MyDB();
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['connect'])) {
    $my_id = $_SESSION['log_id'];
    $ad_id = $_POST['conn_id'];
    $rand_num = rand();
    $hsql = <<<EOF
    SELECT COUNT(hash) as count FROM connect WHERE(user_one = '$my_id'
        AND user_two = '$ad_id') OR(user_one = '$ad_id'
        AND user_two = '$my_id');
    EOF;
    $hret = $db->querySingle($hsql);
    if ($hret == 1) {
        $response = "Your are already connected to '$ad_id'";
    } else {
        $csql = <<<EOF
        INSERT INTO connect(user_one, user_two, hash) VALUES('$my_id', '$ad_id', '$rand_num');
        EOF;
        $cret = $db - > exec($csql);
        if (!$cret) {
            echo "Error connecting to '$ad_id'";
        } else {
            echo "Successful";
        }
    }
}
```

The form executes but not without refreshing the page. Please what is the issue with the `ajax`?

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: Monitor server side echo statements on console and debug your ajax call that where the execution is gone and where it is taking time etc.

Comment: Not at all. When i click submit, it loads the `form action PHP file`

Comment: So it ignores your preventDefault, which is why we ask for errors. It should not really post the form with preventDefault there

Comment: You say at the beginning, the the form is submitted instead of executing the Ajax request. At the end you say that the form executes without refreshing. This sounds confusing and contradictory

Comment: @OkeTega try with Alexandru-Ionut Mihai's answer.

Comment: It didn't work. @LorenzMeyer what i mean is that it ignores the preventDefault

Comment: @OkeTega, try `return false` instead `preventDefault()`. `return false` do both `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation`.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to send form `data` serialized, using `serialize()` method.

Also, use `submit` event for `form`: `$('form').on('submit', function (e) {}`

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "connect_exec.php",
        data: $('form').serialize()
    }).done(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }).fail(function(data) {
       console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#connect').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var ad_id = $('#conn_id').val();
        console.log(ad_id);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "connect_exec.php",
            data: ad_id
        })
        .done(function (response) {
           console.log(response);
        })
        .fail(function (data) {
           console.log(data);
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action='connect_exec.php' method='post' id='connect_form' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <input type='text' name='conn_id' id='conn_id' />
        <input onclick="return;" type='submit' name='connect' class='conn_text' id='connect' value='connect +'>
        </form>
```